# how to dispatch an action on react navigation custom tab bar component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I want to dispatch an action on of the buttons on custom my tab bar navigator and due to react navigation docs we can not use hooks in custom tab bar component
. Any one has an idea to do that?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to prevent the default action of tab bar , and after perventing you can call your own function or any component.

```
  <Tab.Screen
    name="More"
    component={Sleep}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: <Text style={stylee.Fontfamily}>More</Text>,
      tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
        <Icon name="menu-outline" color={color} size={ms(23)} />
      ),
    }}
    listeners={({navigation}) => ({
      tabPress: event => {
        event.preventDefault();     //preventing dafault.
        navigation.openDrawer();    //calling custom 

      },
    })}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

keep in mind , you need to give a component( it's ok if the component is empty or just a text).